# Pantheon File Manager Fork?

Tags: pantheon-files, files, folder, gnome

I believe the Pantheon file manager found in elementary OS is simply called [Pantheon Files](https://github.com/elementary/files), right?

But I'm curious, is this file manager based on another file manager? Based on the GNOME file manager, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Pantheon (Files) is (was) a fork of Marlin. However I think nowadays it is almost entirely rewritten

- https://launchpad.net/pantheon-files
- https://launchpad.net/marlin